# How to send batch emails with formatted HTML in google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

A few months ago with the help of people replying to my post I have managed to write a script that allows me to take data from specific cells of a google sheet and the put that data into an HTML template and send it via Gmail (all in a apps script code). That was great! But I've been trying to make the same script but this time collecting the data to put on the HTML with a loop (cause I want to make the email sending in batches (right now I have to click a button each time I want to send an email, and I have lots of rows (emails) to send).

The main problem is that for populating the HTML with my data I need to call a function from the HMTL, that was cool when I needed to pull the value of a specific Cell (e.g.: A1) but now I need the data of the row specified by the loop (e.g.: first A1, then A2). The function could use the row I need (e.: getName(i) where i is the row, but since I call the function from the HTML I don´t know how to pass the i to the HTML to call the function. I'me trapped in a loop.

Function to get a cell value:

```
   function getname() {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");  // the sheet I'm working on
       var name = sheet.getRange("A1");
       return name.getValues()[0]
   }
```

Function to send the mail:

```
   function sendHTMLmail() {
     var htmlBody =                             HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test').evaluate().getContent();
     MailApp.sendEmail({
             to: "test@gmail.com",
             name: "test",   
             subject: "test",
             htmlBody: htmlBody,
           });  
   }
```

HTML code where I get and print the name

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <base target="_top">
     </head>
     <body>
          <? var name = getname(); ?>

          Hi <?= name ?>
     </body>
   </html>
```

The loop I'd like to improve

```
   function doGet() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sss = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

     for( i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++) {

     var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Prueba').evaluate().getContent();
     MailApp.sendEmail({
             to: "test@gmail.com",
             name: "test",   
             subject: "test",
             htmlBody: htmlBody,
           });  
   }
   }
```

Comment: See the [Simple Mail Merge tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) for instructions on doing this.  It uses a different method but I believe it will get you where you need.

Comment: Just describe what you want and share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Have a look at this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821815/), it may be relevant to your question.